# OpenCV: set matrix values with ranges

Tags: loops, opencv, matrix

I am using the following code for video frames to set matrix values with some range:

```
for ( int row = 0, i = 0; row < srcMat.rows; ++row, i ++ )
{
   uchar* p = medianMat.ptr ( row );
   for ( int col = 0, j = 0; col < srcMat.cols; ++ col, j ++ )
   {
     dstMat ( cv::Range::all(), cv::Range ( i * 5 +1, i * 5 + 4 )).setTo ( *p );
     data++;
   }
}
```

I need to copy the *p to three consecutive values of dstMat, and left one zero space before and after them. That is, if my dstMat is all zero, and *p values are "1,2,3", then my goal is to make dstMat look like" "01110 02220 03330", etc. I hope I made this easy to understand. 
My problem here is: it uses about 70 to 80 milliseconds for one frame, which is too slow for my case. I at most have 30 ms for a single frame. Is there any more efficient way for doing this? 
Besides, the "dstMat" values are all zero outside the "for" loop. Do you have any ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? It's likely that range is checking the boundary on every call - if you write what you are trying to set the pixels to we can probably write somethign faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

somthing like

```
for ( int row = 0; row < dstMat.rows; ++row ){
   uchar* pMed = medianMat.ptr ( row );
   uchar* pDest = dstMat.ptr ( row );  // resulting image
   pDest++; // skip the first place '0'

   for ( int col = 0; col < dstMat.cols; col+=5 )    {
     // copy the value from median into the destination in 3 consecutive values
     *pDest++ = *pMed; // copy 1 to dest
     *pDest++ = *pMed; // copy 1 to dest
     *pDest++ = *pMed; // copy 1 to dest

     pDest+=2; // skip the two zeros
     pMed++; // move to the '2'
   }
}
```

You can use cv::zeros to init a new cv::mat to zero

Comment: Dear Martin, I tried your code, and it seems to work quite perfect. But the only thing is, I changed "uchar* pDest = medianMat.prt (row)" into "uchar* pDest = dstMat.prt (row)", because "dstMat" is the one stores the new values. Then it crashed. I created "dstMat" with zeros as you said. Could you help me? Thank you ver much.

Comment: @ederman, sorry typo. Are the 1,2,3 etc coming from median - or do literally mean 1,2,3 ....? The code assumes that dest is already created and the correct size. ps what is src?

Comment: where do we use "i" in this code by the way? And my medianMat is from one single channel, but my dstMat is with three channels, so in this case, the size of "dstMat" is (5 * 3) = 15 times more than medianMat. For repeating this for three channels, I need to write a loop only for three iterations, I think. But before doing that, this code crashes. Please, I need your help on this. Many thanks.

Comment: By the way, my srcMat and medianMat are the same, actually I should just write medianMat instead. My medianMat size is 600x800=480000, that is from the video frame, and my dstMat is of size 7200000, that is because 480000x5x3. I explained this in my previous answer. Thank you.

Comment: The `i` was a copy/paste from your question. Doing small loops is generally bad - just unroll them into the 3 operations as above. Crashes just mean you need either a debugger - or step through in your mind exactly what is counting/pointing.

Comment: ps Advanced version - once it works you can probably speed up more by writing several pixels at once. Instead of copying the same byte three times make a 32bit int with that byte repeated (using bitshift) then write a single int once.