# Android OpenCV: drawing matches with feature2d

Tags: java, android, opencv

I can't get this function to work. Basically I am doing feature detection and matching with a reference image. I want to overlay the matched features on top of my input image. Here is my code:

```
public Mat startProcessing(Mat inputImage) {

    Imgproc.cvtColor(inputImage, rgb, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
    myFeatures.detect(rgb, keypoints);
    descriptorExtractor.compute(inputImage, keypoints, imageDescriptors);
    descriptorMatcher.match(templateDescriptors, imageDescriptors, matches);

    Features2d.drawMatches(rgb, keypoints, templateImage, templateKeypoints, matches, rgb); 

    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgb, outputImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
    return outputImage;
}
```

It's Features2d.drawMatches which is specifically the problem. According to the Android error I've gotten, some dimensions aren't lining up. Truth be told, I'm not even sure how `drawMatches` is supposed to work on Android because there's no documentation anywhere.

What I want to be able to do is draw the matches on top of the inputImage. I've gotten `Feature2d.drawKeypoints` to work, but I'm unsure how I would go about converting `MatOfDMatch matches` to a `MatOfKeypoint` object. Also I'm not even sure if that's how the MatOfDMatch works - doesn't it have some associativity inside of it corresponding to the descriptors?

Sorry for being all over the place, I'm having a really hard time using OpenCV with Android. The C++ documentation out there is good, but there's little in the way of Android materials. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing that I've noticed is that you are converting images from one color space to another. It's confusing a little bit. If you want to draw matches on greyscale images, it is not necessary to perform this image conversion. 
Other thing, you are detecting keypoints on RGB image and then extracting descriptors from original image(as I can see it is greyscale)

Also I suggest you to check inside of your function if images are of the same type. Just print in log `inputImage` object and see if both are of type `CV_8UC3` or equivalent. Basically your code should be like this:

```
Mat imageOut = inputImage.clone();
Features2d.drawMatches(inputImage, keypoints, templateImage, templateKeypoints, matches, imageOut);
Highgui.imwrite("result_match.jpeg", imageOut);
```

Answering to another your questions:

Q:I'm unsure how I would go about converting `MatOfDMatch` matches to a `MatOfKeypoint` object.
A:You do not need to do it, because `drawMatches` function receives `MatOfKeypoint` of input image and also of template image. Then when you passing `MatOfDMatch` it draws matches between matched received kypoints.

Q:Also I'm not even sure if that's how the `MatOfDMatch` works - doesn't it have some associativity inside of it corresponding to the descriptors?
A:Yes it have. If you will do `matches.toList(0).queryIdx` and `matches.toList(0).trainIdx` you will get the index of `inputImage`'s keypoint, which matches with `templateImage`'s keypoint  of the first match.

Comment: Thanks so far. I started using imageOut = inputImage.clone() and this lets drawMatches work. However I want to return this imageOut as what the user sees on the camera but the dimensions are slightly different - it's 704*480 rather than my camera resolution of 640*480. Given that my template image has width 64 it looks like drawMatches is putting them side-by-side. Can I just show a rectangle or something over the matched area on the input image?

Comment: Yes I think so. Transform matches and keypoints to list `List<DMatch> matches_list = matches.toList();List<KeyPoint> kp_list = keypoints.toList();` and then iterate through the list `kp_list.get(matches_list.get(i).queryIdx)` and find the minimum and maximum X and Y of matched keypoints in order to encounter two points that will define your rectangle. Then define a rectangle `Rect roi = new Rect(new Point(minX,minY),new Point(maxX,maxY))` and then just do `Mat imageFinal = new Mat(inputImage, roi);` and it will crop only the matched area