# Object detection with OpenCV Feature Matching with a threshold/similarity score - Java/C++

Tags: opencv, image-processing, feature-detection, object-detection, feature-extraction

I am in the process of creating a small program which detects objects(small image) in the large image and I am using OpenCV java. 
As I have to consider rotation and scaling I have used FeatureDetector.BRISK and DescriptorExtractor.BRISK.

Following approach is used to filter the match results to get the best matches only.

I have two questions

1. Is there a way to find the below min_dist and max_dist with the loop I have used?
2. Most important question - Now the problem is I need to use these matches to determine whether the object(template) found or not. Would be great if some one help me here.

Thanks in advance.

```
    FeatureDetector  fd = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.BRISK); 
    final MatOfKeyPoint keyPointsLarge = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    final MatOfKeyPoint keyPointsSmall = new MatOfKeyPoint();

    fd.detect(largeImage, keyPointsLarge);
    fd.detect(smallImage, keyPointsSmall);

    System.out.println("keyPoints.size() : "+keyPointsLarge.size());
    System.out.println("keyPoints2.size() : "+keyPointsSmall.size());

    Mat descriptorsLarge = new Mat();
    Mat descriptorsSmall = new Mat();

    DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.BRISK);
    extractor.compute(largeImage, keyPointsLarge, descriptorsLarge);
    extractor.compute(smallImage, keyPointsSmall, descriptorsSmall);

    System.out.println("descriptorsA.size() : "+descriptorsLarge.size());
    System.out.println("descriptorsB.size() : "+descriptorsSmall.size());

    MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();

    DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMINGLUT);
    matcher.match(descriptorsLarge, descriptorsSmall, matches);

    System.out.println("matches.size() : "+matches.size());

    MatOfDMatch matchesFiltered = new MatOfDMatch();

    List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();
    List<DMatch> bestMatches= new ArrayList<DMatch>();

    Double max_dist = 0.0;
    Double min_dist = 100.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matchesList.size(); i++)
    {
        Double dist = (double) matchesList.get(i).distance;

        if (dist < min_dist && dist != 0)
        {
            min_dist = dist;
        }

        if (dist > max_dist)
        {
            max_dist = dist;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("max_dist : "+max_dist);
    System.out.println("min_dist : "+min_dist);

    double threshold = 3 * min_dist;
    double threshold2 = 2 * min_dist;

    if (threshold2 >= max_dist)
    {
        threshold = min_dist * 1.1;
    }
    else if (threshold >= max_dist)
    {
        threshold = threshold2 * 1.4;
    }

    System.out.println("Threshold : "+threshold);

    for (int i = 0; i < matchesList.size(); i++)
    {
        Double dist = (double) matchesList.get(i).distance;
        System.out.println(String.format(i + " match distance best : %s", dist));
        if (dist < threshold)
        {
            bestMatches.add(matches.toList().get(i));
            System.out.println(String.format(i + " best match added : %s", dist));
        }
    }


    matchesFiltered.fromList(bestMatches);

    System.out.println("matchesFiltered.size() : " + matchesFiltered.size());
```

---

### Edit

Edited my code as follows.I know still it's not the best way to come to a conclusion whether the object found or not based on no of best matches.
So please share your views.

```
    System.out.println("max_dist : "+max_dist);
    System.out.println("min_dist : "+min_dist);

    if(min_dist > 50 )
    {
        System.out.println("No match found");
        System.out.println("Just return ");
        return false;
    }

    double threshold = 3 * min_dist;
    double threshold2 = 2 * min_dist;

    if (threshold > 75)
    {
        threshold  = 75;
    }
    else if (threshold2 >= max_dist)
    {
        threshold = min_dist * 1.1;
    }
    else if (threshold >= max_dist)
    {
        threshold = threshold2 * 1.4;
    }

    System.out.println("Threshold : "+threshold);

    for (int i = 0; i < matchesList.size(); i++)
    {
        Double dist = (double) matchesList.get(i).distance;

        if (dist < threshold)
        {
            bestMatches.add(matches.toList().get(i));
            //System.out.println(String.format(i + " best match added : %s", dist));
        }
    }

    matchesFiltered.fromList(bestMatches);

    System.out.println("matchesFiltered.size() : " + matchesFiltered.size());


    if(matchesFiltered.rows() >= 1)
    {
        System.out.println("match found");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code, which gives me thousand of ideas. Thanks a lot for sharing. But there are too many false positives. I think otherwise you wouldn't ask here

Answer (score 1):

Your Edited code is working fine for me, and working perfectly,

Following are changes that i have done in your code for  detecting objects(small image) in the large image :

1. using SURF method for feature detection as well as feature extraction.(SURF is available in opencv 4.1.1 for Android and earlier, after that it have been removed from that, so here i have used opencv 4.1.1)
2. change threshold of image matched or not from 1 to 4, in following line

   if(matchesFiltered.rows() >= 1)

to

```
if(matchesFiltered.rows() >= 4)
```

only this changes have worked perfectly for me, make sure that object/small image have rich texture(atleast should have keypoints that can be matched)

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches for detecting objects inside images. Just put some links here:

- [Open CV 2 Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849513244), Chapter 8/9
- http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html
- http://robocv.blogspot.de/2012/02/real-time-object-detection-in-opencv.html

The last link shows a way to calculate the min and max value, should be nearly the same in Java. All links should hopefully show some ideas how to match objects.

I also recognized that there are a lot of magic numbers inside your code. Maybe you could put them in variables to reduce the possibility of error and have a better overview.

Comment: thanks for the references,Actually I have started writing this code with tutorial in the 2nd link :-) .
And regarding the magic numbers, ya, this is a extracted and modified version of my code to add on this forum, I have addressed those numbers into variables already. Thanks for pointing it too.

My issue is although all these examples shows how to find best matches and draw the final outpout none of them talks about arriving to a conclusion on whether the object is FOUND OR NOT using some threshold. It would be great if I can get an idea on that.