# Creating a rectangle when the camera starts

Tags: opencv

I am trying to make an application that detect an ID card So how can I make a rectangle appears when the camera starts by using OpenCV ?

And the user has to fit the credit card inside that box and the program knows that the card fits it.

I tried to search but I didn't reach anything so any links or solutions would be great.

Comment: What about the drawing function [rectangle](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle)?

Comment: then ? how can the program knows that the cards fits the rectangle ?

Comment: Oh well... Overly broad question then... Have a further look on SO, there are a lot of question on this topic

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `rectangle()` for drawing a rectangle.

Regarding the implementation of detecting an ID card, I would try using feature matching (on a matrix of the rectangle's area), then measure the "level" of matches to determine positive and negative matches. This will require a degree of refining to determine the desired thresholds.

[This](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html) page may be helpful.

You may also find this post helpful [Object detection with OpenCV Feature Matching with a threshold/similarity score - Java/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898480/object-detection-with-opencv-feature-matching-with-a-threshold-similarity-score)