# Opencv template matching marking wrong spot in the source image in android

Tags: android, image, opencv, template-matching

As i understand template matching finds areas of an image that match (are similar) to a template image (patch) according to
[this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)

So i have two images of different dimension. And when i am trying to match my template image with the source image it usually marks the wrong area in the image.

**Source Image**

[image]

**Template image**

[image]

**Output image**

[image]

It works fine with threshold value if the images are of same dimension. What needs to be done to overcome this problem?? Or can i use template matching in this scenario??

Comment: Exactly because they have different dimensions. Template matching is **not** scale (nor rotation) invariant. Try features matching in this case.

Comment: try http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/ and in addition just for the future: template matching isn't rotation invariant either.

Comment: do u know any example of feature matching in java?? and also any theory on basis of what this algorithm works @Miki

Comment: @Fay007 check for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898480/object-detection-with-opencv-feature-matching-with-a-threshold-similarity-score). Or [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html). [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_meaning/py_features_meaning.html#features-meaning) some basic concepts. Google for more :D

Comment: i have already gone through them :P @Miki

Comment: Then you're on the right path. Just follow it :D

Comment: @Micka  i am gonna look into it!! but how thats gonna help me?? just explain to me is that blog is related to my problem ??

Comment: it shows how to make the matchTemplate function scale invariant by calling it iteratively for multiple scales.

Comment: so u are suggesting me to change the scale of the captured image into the template image scale ?? @Micka

Comment: basically yes. This could be a possible solution. But might be very slow because you have to resize the image many times because you don't know the final scale.