# Image processing i.e. matching similar images in java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, image-scaling

Is there a way where i can match some sort of screenshots with earlier stored images in my system.
Consider 2 images i want to compare A and B.
A is full screenshot of monitor whereas B corresponds to a particular window say a small image.
My problem is to find whether A contains B or not?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For image processing I suggest using OpenCV library to get started. It has feature detectors which you can use to detect and find similar objects within an image like this. There are quite a few examples online you can use to perform the function you need. It is a pretty big topic so I can't share a lot, but I hope this can give you a head start :)

[Image Similarity Java](http://xmlmanager.blogspot.my/2015/09/opencv-comparing-image-similarity-using.html)

[Feature Matching Java (Stackoverflow answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898480/object-detection-with-opencv-feature-matching-with-a-threshold-similarity-score)

[image: Feature Matching Example]

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a whole lot out there in terms of Java stuff that does image matching. I've found (maybe) [a starting point for you](http://mindmeat.blogspot.com/2008/07/java-image-comparison.html), but be aware that this is a really complex topic. [Related StackOverflow topic here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644960/java-library-to-compare-image-similarity)