# Printing Mat matrix on different lines

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, mat

I am using C++. I want to print the matrix of a Mat object on different lines like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/1FsNmah.png]

What I have right now is

```
cout << m <<endl <<endl;
```

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: sorry i dont know why the last line is not appearing. It's cout <<matrix_f<< endl <<endl;

Comment: I fixed the formatting, but can you explain what m or matrix_f is (declaration)?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention. "matrix_f" is the name of the Mat object(Mat matrix_f;)

Comment: Do you have just one Mat object and want to print it out, or do you have multiple, and they need to be printed out like in the checker-board pattern you showed in the question?

Comment: i will have 3 Mat matrices which will need to be printed as in the picture in command line

Answer (score 3):

In this case (referring to the comments) you need to print your matrices row-wise. Make use of m.row() and m.at(). Supposed that you have 3x3 matrices as in the image:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    Mat row1 = m1.row (i);
    Mat row2 = m2.row (i);
    Mat row3 = m3.row (i);

    // this can be replaced by a loop, I spell it out for the sake of clearness
    cout << row1.at(0, 0) << " " << row1.at (0, 1) << " " << row1.at (0, 2) << "\t"
         << row2.at(0, 0) << " " << row2.at (0, 1) << " " << row2.at (0, 2) << "\t"
         << row3.at(0, 0) << " " << row3.at (0, 1) << " " << row3.at (0, 2) << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to print it to command line, i suggest looking at 
[OpenCV: Matrix Iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977954/opencv-matrix-iteration)

If you are doing this quite frequently, although not very recommended, you can derive your own Matrix class and override the `<<` operator  to print it the way you want it to (as in the link above)